# Como resolver erro de encode

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres, encode

Recentemente eu tive uma dúvida aqui sobre como resolver um problema de acento �, e conseguiram me ajudar da seguinte forma: 
`echo utf8_encode($row['nome']);`.

Mas ficou um pequeno erro, que não estou conseguindo resolver que é o [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]. Esse quadrado era pra ser esse traço: `–`. Ele é um pouco diferente do normal: `-`.

Quando digito no *HTML* normalmente ele funciona, mas quando 
é puxando do banco fica dessa forma.

Comment: é um HTML Entities?

Comment: Qual charset do banco de dados? Você está utilizando utf8_unicode_ci ou utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Comment: É o utf8_unicode_ci no banco. HTML comum.